# Custom AssemblyLoadContext failing to load Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**Edit:  I have uploaded the source code for the issue to GitHub if you would like to download:  https://github.com/bryanenroute/assemblyloadcontext-issue**

I have a .NET Core 3.0 console application that references a .NET Standard 2.0 class library with a single interface (IModule).  I also have a ASP.NET Core 3.0 application that references the same .NET Standard 2.0 class library and implements the interface (Module : IModule).

I am trying to load the ASP.NET Core assembly from the .NET Core console application using a custom AssemblyLoadContext and a common class library interface (IModule)... a simple plugin system.

Unfortunately, the ASP.NET Core module/plugin fails in the ALC override function for Load(AssemblyName) with the following exception:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.**

When I try with a different project type (e.g. .NET Core Console Application or .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library), the module/plugin loads as intended.

Here's the Console app code:

```
using NetStandardCommon;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace NetCoreConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadNetCoreModule();
            LoadAspNetCoreModule();
        }

        static void LoadNetCoreModule()
        {
            //Works!
            FileInfo asm = new FileInfo(@"..\..\..\..\NetCoreModule\bin\debug\netcoreapp3.0\NetCoreModule.dll");
            var moduleDirectory = asm.DirectoryName;

            ModuleAssemblyLoadContext context = new ModuleAssemblyLoadContext(asm.Name, moduleDirectory, typeof(IModule));
            context.Scan();

            foreach (var module in context.GetImplementations<IModule>())
            {
                module.Start();
            }
        }

        static void LoadAspNetCoreModule()
        {
            //Fails!
            FileInfo asm = new FileInfo(@"..\..\..\..\AspNetCoreApp\bin\debug\netcoreapp3.0\AspNetCoreApp.dll");
            var moduleDirectory = asm.DirectoryName;

            ModuleAssemblyLoadContext context = new ModuleAssemblyLoadContext(asm.Name, moduleDirectory, typeof(IModule));
            context.Scan();

            foreach (var module in context.GetImplementations<IModule>())
            {
                module.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the ModuleAssemblyLoadContext code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Linq;

namespace NetCoreConsoleApp
{
    public class ModuleAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private List<Assembly> _loaded;
        private Dictionary<string, Assembly> _shared;

        private string _path;

        private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

        public ModuleAssemblyLoadContext(string name, string path, params Type[] sharedTypes) : base(name)
        {
            _path = path;
            _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(_path);

            _loaded = new List<Assembly>();
            _shared = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

            if (sharedTypes != null)
            {
                foreach (Type sharedType in sharedTypes)
                {
                    _shared[Path.GetFileName(sharedType.Assembly.Location)] = sharedType.Assembly;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Scan()
        {
            foreach (string dll in Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path, "*.dll"))
            {
                var file = Path.GetFileName(dll);

                if (_shared.ContainsKey(file))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var asm = this.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dll);

                _loaded.Add(asm);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetImplementations<T>()
        {
            return _loaded
                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t))
                .Cast<T>();
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            string filename = $"{assemblyName.Name}.dll";
            if (_shared.ContainsKey(filename))
            {
                return _shared[filename];
            }

            string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
        {
            string libraryPath = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
            if (libraryPath != null)
            {
                return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(libraryPath);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried modifying the ALC Load function to load the assemblies directly from the shared folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.0.0) which lets the execution continue a bit farther, but it ultimately fails with the following exception:

**An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)**

Here's the revised Load function:

```
        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            string filename = $"{assemblyName.Name}.dll";
            if (_shared.ContainsKey(filename))
            {
                return _shared[filename];
            }

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.0.0\" + filename))
                {
                    return Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.0.0\" + filename);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Message displayed is 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)'
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        }
```

I'm excited about the possibilities of loading/unloading assemblies for a .net Core plugin system, but I'm struggling to get over this hurdle.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue about a month ago with loading a Assembly to my SQL server. Are you using virtual drives to store your Assembly? I found out that our share drive actual drive path was a E drive and not a P drive which is what is mapped on my computer. I was virtually connected to it, so I had to give the real Drive path which started with E instead of P. Also, your program might be mapping it to the wrong drive as well. I would check that, and if that doesn't help I have about 3-4 more things to try as far as this particular issue in concerned.

Comment: Good thought, but all projects/assemblies are on the local C drive

Answer (score 0):

I believe the library might also need to be built with the target framework set to .NetCore 3.0 (netcoreapp3.0).

Comment: I tried switching the common library (ClassLibrary1) to target netcoreapp3.0 instead of netstandard2.0.  Unfortunately, the same error occurs.